# What characters (race/class) are shown in the original (Vanilla) World Of Warcraft Cinematic Trailer?

Tags: video-games, character-identification, races, warcraft, trailer

In the original (Vanilla) [World Of Warcraft Cinematic Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYK_Gqyf48Y), the one that plays every time the game starts up, the one we have all watched many times, there are different characters each doing various things in the trailer. Some of these characters, that is their race and class, are pretty distinguishable and easy to identify, but there are a couple characters that are kind of hard to tell, what they are exactly, and I've just been wondering about it for years. I'm sure others have maybe wondered this as well.

Here is a list of characters that I've been able to identify in the trailer, along with the time of their first appearance in the trailer:

```
Dwarf Hunter ~ 1:05
Night Elf Druid ~1:35
Undead Warlock ~ 2:00 ???
Tauren Shaman ~ 2:15 ???
Orc Warrior ~ 2:30
Human Mage ~ 2:44
```

I feel somewhat confident in some of my guesses, but others, the ones with the ??? marks, I'm not sure of. Some cursory Googling didn't turn up anything, I don't know if an official list exists or what have you, but hopefully someone else knows? :)

This question was deemed off-topic on the [Gaming SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) , and this site was suggested as possible better place for it.

Comment: Wow. Hard to fathom why this was off-topic at Gaming - it's directly asking about an in-game cinematic and which in-game race/class combinations it depicts. Oh well, their loss is our gain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The World of Warcraft [Wiki page](http://wowpedia.org/Seasons_of_War) seems quite well informed on this issue.

It describes the introduction thusly:

> Several establishing shots are then shown, introducing several of the
> game's playable races and classes: **a dwarf hunter, a night elf druid,
> a Forsaken warlock, a tauren shaman, an orc warrior, and a human mage.**
>
> It then transitions into a series of sequences showing the various
> characters doing battle against each other, culminating with the
> tauren smashing a totem into the camera and the game's logo appearing.